# wxWidgets get wxlistctrl header label

Tags: wxwidgets, listctrl

How can I retrieve label information for a wxlistctrl ?
I've tried something like :

```
wxListItem  itemCol;

m_listCtrl->GetColumn(0, itemCol);
printf("%s\n", itemCol.GetText().c_str());
```

but it doesn't  work, I get an empty string !

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wxListItem column;
column.SetText(_("Column 1"));
m_List->InsertColumn(0, column);

wxListItem result;
result.SetMask(wxLIST_MASK_TEXT);
m_List->GetColumn(0, result);
wxMessageBox(result.GetText());
```